# is it possible to stack cabal sandboxes?

Tags: haskell, package, sandbox, ghc, cabal

Is it possible to "stack" cabal sandboxes or specify a "package.d" search path?

I'd like to install frequently used packages into a common sandbox that projects can use but don't update.

There is a `world-file` parameter in the `cabal.sandbox.config` file, but I couldn't find any reference to it in the `Cabal` source.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `world-file` refers to an optional function by which `cabal-install` will maintain a plaintext list of packages requested for install, perhaps modeled on Gentoo's `/var/lib/portage/world` and similar systems. Cabal doesn't use that file for anything.

Your proposed "nested sandboxes" might cause the same problems as global or per-user installations: various packages would have to have a consistent set of dependencies.

It's possible to *share* a single sandbox between projects with the `--sandbox=DIR` parameter to `cabal sandbox`.